# How to tell which module does the package belong to?

Tags: java, module, java-9, java-module, jdeps

Given some package `foo.bar`, how do I find which module does it belong to?

For example, package `java.util` belongs to module `java.base`. I can verify it by typing in `jdeps -m java.base` and by going through the long output. This however assumes my prior knowledge that package `java.util` belongs to module `java.base`.

How can I verify which module does the package belong to?

Comment: Modules export packages, please see here: http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/261

Comment: Huh interesting. I was thinking that since I can declare my own `java.util` package in my own module, the question of "which module does `java.util` belong to" isn't well defined. But after trying it out, I realised that I can't do that anymore in Java 9+. TIL

Comment: What is the actual use case for this specifically? I mean you can generally perform `jdeps` over a complete application too, so your prior knowledge need not be scoped.

Comment: @Sweeper you could never define your own `java.util` package. All qualified names starting with `java.` were reserved even before Java 9. For other non-reserved names, you still can define packages with the same name but different class loaders, as long as they belong to the unnamed module of either loader or to different module layers without a parent-child relationship.

Comment: @user16320675 changing the contents of the `java.util` package is entirely different to creating a different package with the same name at runtime. The modified `java.util` package would still belong to the `java.base` module.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
Optional<Module> found = ModuleLayer
        .boot()
        .modules()
        .stream()
        .filter(module -> module.getPackages().contains("java.util"))
        .findFirst();
```